# Stargate - Destiny's Gate Address from Icarus base

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

Simple question - What is the address they dial to connect with the Ancient ship Destiny in Stargate Universe from Icarus base.

I have found the address on [Stargate Wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Destiny) - however they have an unconfirmed order, and not sure of the validity of this.

Any help deciphering the above would be great!

Comment: Mallozzi's image gives you Earth's address _from_ Destiny, so it's the wrong direction

Comment: Wow good spotting!

Comment: @m.t.bennett - I've edited to show the full address, albeit the sequence is unknown. Short of a Word Of God answer from Malozzi, this is as good as you'll get

Comment: @Richard I've been trying to contact Malozzi from his blog but no luck :(

Answer (score 6):

While the Stargate Wiki lists the following glyphs as being part of the address for the Destiny [image]

Images from the actual episode suggest the symbols below are actually the right ones, with the caveat that the full *sequence* isn't known;

[image]

You can see some of those glyphs on the DHD at Icarus base during the evacuation;

[image]

During the (failed) dialling attempt we see the following glyphs in order;

1st
[image]

7th
[image]

8th?
[image]

and of course the home symbol which, for some reason seems to be the same as Earth's. 
[image]

We can also see the base address symbols in wider detail here, although again the order is not shown;

[image]

Since Icarus base was destroyed, knowing the order of dialling seems pretty moot anyway :-)

Comment: Well, not moot - the Lucian Alliance found another Icarus planet to use.  And there's probably more out there.

Comment: They used Earth's symbols as the point of origin because it is part of the 9-chevron address, regardless of where your are dialing from. In the pilot episode they did mention that in order to reach Destiny, they would need to dial it as if they were on Earth.

Comment: _"and of course the home address which, for some reason seems to be the same as Earth's"_ It's not. This was an important plot point.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - I, of course meant "home symbol" not "home address". Good catch

Comment: @Richard: Well I meant the "home symbol" too. It _wasn't_ posited as being the "home symbol" for that planet, so it's not weird. It's just that the final chevron in Destiny's address did not use a "home symbol" or point of origin.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately only the 1st, 7th and 9th chevrons are seen being encoded, so we don't actually know the order to dial for *Destiny*'s address from Icarus Base.